# Task<List<T>> returns List.Count=0 but has 116 Elements

Tags: c#, wcf, task, windows, multitasking

I really don't know what the problem is. I've an win8.1 App which is calling a WCF Method for getting some Data. When i debug the WCF it returns a `Task<List<T>>` with `List.Count=116` Elements in the List but when the List (Task) "arrives" in my App it always says `List.Count=0`.

Tested with WCF-Testclient too - result:
[image]

And the result i get in my Win8 App:

[image]

Call:

```
private List<Person> getPersonList()
{
    IService client = CustomServiceBinding.GetClientForIService();
    try
    {
        if (client != null && ((IClientChannel)client).State == CommunicationState.Opened))
        {
             var personList = client.GetPersonStateList(terminalName);

             personList.Wait(Timeout.Infinite);

             if (personList.IsCompleted)
             {          
                 if (personList.Result == null || personList.Result.Count <= 0)
                 {                            
                      // i'm ALWAYS landing here because the List has no Elements
                      // but when the method in the WCF returns the List had 116 Elements
                      // where do they get lost?
                 }
                 else
                 {                            
                      foreach (var item in personList.Result)
                      {
                           loginTextbox.Text += "Yeah";
                      }
                 }
             }
        }
    }     
    catch (CommunicationObjectFaultedException cofe)
    {
         ExceptionHandling(cofe);

         if (client != null)
         {
              ((IClientChannel)client).Abort();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         ExceptionHandling(ex);

         if (client != null)
         {
              ((IClientChannel)client).Abort();
         }
    }
    finally
    {
         if (client != null)
         {
              ((IClientChannel)client).Close();
              ((IClientChannel)client).Dispose();
         }
    }
 }
```

Method in WCF:

```
public async Task<List<Person>> GetPersonStateList(string terminal)
{
    Task<List<Person>> t = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
        try
        {                        
             //calling another WCF - returns 116 Elements
             //validatePerson always returns true (hardcoded for testing)    
             currentPersonList = ServiceBinding.getCurrentPersonList().GetPersonEnumeration().Where(x => validatePerson(x));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             currentPersonList = null;
             ExceptionContainer myException = new ExceptionContainer("Message: " + ex.Message);
             throw new FaultException<ExceptionContainer>(myException);
        }


        if (currentPersonList != null && currentPersonList.Count() > 0)
        {                            
            foreach (var item in currentPersonList)
            {                                
                 TimeSpan ts;

                 var dailyTimes = item.GetDailyTimeEnumeration();

                 foreach (var day in dailyTimes)
                 {                                    
                       ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, (int)day.RawValue);

                       personList.Add(new Person() { Name = item.firstname + " " + item.lastname, dailyTime = ts });
                 }
            }
        }
        else
        {               
              // i never get in here             
              personList = null;
        }

        // at this point the personList has 116 valid Elements
        return personList;
    });

    // this "t" has a List with 116 Elements at the return point
    return await t;
}
```

What am i missing here? Did i forget something? Do i have to lock something (if yes, WHAT should i lock and where?)?

** **EDITED** **

Added more code examples in WCF Method and two Screenshots from the results i get in WCF and in Win8 App.

** **EDITED** **

Now i've changed a few things in coding in the given methods above.

Second one is not returning a `Task<List<Person>>` but just a `List<Person>`.

The first Method is shortened and looks like this:

```
private async void updateUI(object sender, object e)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
            TM2K_Service client = IAGServiceBinding.GetClientForTM2K();
            try
            {
                if (client != null)
                {
                    string terminalName = getTerminalName().ToLower();

                    // asynchronous
                    var personList = await client.GetPersonStateList(terminalName);


                    if (personList == null || personList.Count <= 0)
                    {
                        // BUT I'M STILL STUCK HERE WITH A LIST WITH ZERO ELEMENTS (Count=0)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         foreach (var item in personList.Result)
                         {
                             loginTextbox.Text += "Yeah";
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                ExceptionHandling(x);
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            ExceptionHandling(ex);
        }
    }
```

I get the same Results when i'm calling the IIS published WCF as when i call the WCF-Testclient `var personList Count=0`.

** **EDIT** **

I found out it's a problem with deserializing of collections or generic lists. When you add a servicereference via visual studio (clicking) it sets default collection types for deserialization. I'm working with ChannelFactory so i have to set it as `KnownType(typeof)`? But i'm fairly new to this niveau of coding in WCF or setting programmatically servicereferences on clientside - how and where do i set these attributes? And i tried the known type `IList<>` too or an `Array` or an `ObservableCollection`. No chance to deserialize received data.

How and which attributes do i have to set for deserialization?

Comment: Can you reduce this to a minimal reproducible example? Do you see the same behavior when WCF is removed from the equation? On a side note, using `Task.Run` in WCF isn't necessary or beneficial - you can just as easily return `List<Person>`.

Comment: what does the `// querying everything i need` look like? are you disposing some object which makes the list "invalid" or something? for instance, would it work if you do `return personList.ToList()` in the `Task.Run(..)`?

Comment: Sorry my fault - not null but `Count = 0`! as i wrote - `return await t;` has a List with 116 Elements (with valid Data) and i can't write the code in here because i'm just calling another wcf which delivers these Elements. `return personList;` also has 116 Elements (with valid Data) at the end so the call to this second WCF works perfectly. But i'll try to show you what happens inside the WCF.

Comment: where should i post this when not here? btw - i changed coding example a little bit!

Comment: added Testresults from WCF-Testclient and from coding in Win8 App.

Comment: Could you please reopen this question? Or could you tell me which additional Infos you need or whats wrong with this question? Thank you!!

Comment: WCF already uses different threads for different request. You gain nothing by using `Task.Run` in your WCF method except wasting another thread while the request thread is waiting for a result. You should have made the *client* side call `async `though instead of trying to wait and process raw Tasks. The proxy generator can create asynchronous methods no matter how you code the server - otherwise you wouldn't be able to call non .NET services asynchronously

Comment: Are you seeing the Count==0 programmatically or only in the debugger? If it's only in the debugger, it could be a case of compiler optimization making it not available to the debugger.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - i just reproduced existing methods! Will change it as fast as i can! Thank you!

Comment: @MattC - programmatically/debugger/on applications UI - no data, nothing to show on the ui etc.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - i've changed client method to `asny/await` and serverside return is just a `List<Person>` and no `Task<List<Person>>` but the result is the same = serverside list has at point of return 116 Elements, clientside list has 0 Elements. Doesn't matter if i make a call to the iis published WCF or to the WCF-Testclient.

Comment: Try changing the client call to be a synchronous call. I.e. on the client side the method defined in the contract interface is:
    List<Person> GetPersonStateList(string terminal);
That way you can see if it's a problem with being a Task on the client side or if it's unrelated to Task's.

Comment: I found out it's a problem with deserializing of collections or generic lists. when you add a servicereference via visual studio (clicking) it sets default collection types for deserialization. I'm working with ChannelFactory so i have to set it as `KnownType(typeof)`? But i'm fairly new to this niveau of coding in WCF - how and where do i set these attributes? I know i've to code it client side. that's it. And i tried the known type `IList<>` too or an array. No chance to deserialize received data.